# Get value from property in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, foreach

I am having an issue getting the values from a property of a type viewmodel I am passing in.  This is my current method, I believe the name of the property is being stored right, but I can't seem to get the value to work.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I believe I will have problems with the dictionary when the type of value is not always a string also, but that is another problem for later :).

Here is the method taking in the viewmodel type:

```
public Type ConvertModel(Type mytype) {
            Dictionary<string,string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();

            foreach (var prop in mytype.GetProperties())
            {
               dic.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(mytype,null).ToString());
            }

            //return mytype;
        }
```

This is how that method is being called(Ignore the method name I am just trying an idea out):

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewmodel = new myViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = "Shawn",
                LastName = "Michaels"
            };

            var newType = ConvertModel(viewmodel.GetType());

            return View();
        }
```

The sample output is that I would eventually pass back another model related to the viewModel (say UserViewModel and UserModel, where UserModel would be filled with the UserViewModel properties and values, except the method should tank in any 2 related models like above.)

Comment: You need to post the your type and sample output to make it easier to understand

Comment: I edited with that info.

Answer (score 1):

Cause the property can be null, then raise the error so you can do one of these options:

**Updateing**

Just make sure you pass instance of object instead of type:

Instead of this
   public Type ConvertModel(Type mytype) {

use below code

```
public T ConvertModel<T>(T obj) 
{
   var dic = new Dictionary<string,object>();
   foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
      dic.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj,null));
   }
```

**First:** Create Dictionary as obejct

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string,object>();
foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    dic.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj,null));
}
```

**Second:** You can cast to string and if can not cast put null in Dictionary

```
foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    dic.Add(prop.Name, (string)prop.GetValue(obj,null));
}
```

Or

```
foreach (var prop in mytype.GetProperties())
{
    dic.Add(prop.Name, Convert.ToString(prop.GetValue(mytype,null)));
}
```

Comment: I tried the above answer, I get the following error when adding to the dictionary.  An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Thats a different error, instead pass type you should pass instance

Comment: Ahhh, it was both of the above ones. I am looking into passing it as something other than a type right now.

Comment: just check my updated, for getting property value you should pass instance object, not type